# Visual Studio-style window management for Windows in general?

Tags: windows, windows-10, window-manager

I really like the way Visual Studio allows you to easily tile, tab, and/or float any Visual Studio pane, however you prefer, using drag-and-drop operations.

Is there any existing software which provides this capability for organizing standard windows in the Windows GUI (perhaps activated by some kind of modifier key, so it doesn't interfere with standard drag-and-drop support)?

Specifically, I want the ability to: tile arbitrary windows, stack arbitrary windows into a single tile with tabs to switch between them, and detach windows into (conventional) floating mode. Windows 10 has better native tiling than previous versions but I miss Visual Studio's flexibility, ease of splitting an existing tile into halves, and ability to easily tab and un-tab panes.

It would need to work on Windows 10, and support HiDPI displays and multiple monitors. Preferably primarily mouse-driven but hotkey commands are nice too.

Comment: Visual Studio has a template for a Visual Studio like UI design allowing you to write your own application using the template. I have tried it out a time or two with sample applications and there seems to be some mega plumbing underneath the templates and API which requires cooperation between windows.